# Passing vector pointer as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to pass the vector of pointer to insertVector function. Since I don't know size of array of vector in main function, I create the array of vector object in insertVector function. And I got error message like "Bus error (core dumped)".It's workable when I new the object like following in main function.  What am I doing wrong here? 
    vector* ivec = new vector[5];
I am expecting the result like that.
index:0
test
haha
index:1
test
haha
index:2
test
haha
index:3
test
haha
index:4
test
haha

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<cstring>
        #include<vector>
        using namespace std;

        int insertVector(vector<string> *input)
        {
           int size = 5;
           input = new vector<string>[size];

           for(int k=0; k < size; k++)
           {
              (*input).push_back("test");
              for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
              {
                (*input).push_back("haha");
              }
              input++;
           }
           return size;
        }

        int main()
        {
           vector<string>* ivec;
           int i = insertVector(ivec);

           for(int iy = 0; iy < i; ++iy)
           {
              vector<string>:: iterator iter = ivec[iy].begin();
              cout << "index:" << iy << endl;
              for(int ix = 0; iter != ivec[iy].end(); ++iter, ++ix)
              {
                  cout << *iter << endl;
              }
           }

           return 0;
        }
```

Comment: This use of pointers is how C programs are normally written.  Why not pass a vector by reference?

Comment: Tracking a container's size also smells like C programming.  Did you know that a `vector` implicitly knows its own size?  You don't have to track it.

Comment: You're (a) incorrectly passing a pointer by-value, and (b) leaking memory and invoking *undefined behavior* as a result of (a). Changing your parameter to `vector<string>*& input` will address your problem (the ensuing memory leak in `main()` not withstanding), but not the real issue, namely doing this in the presented fashion in the first place.

Comment: Why not use a vector of vectors - `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void AllocateVector(std::vector<int> **pIntVector)
{
    *pIntVector = new std::vector<int>[10];
    (*pIntVector)->push_back(10);
    (*pIntVector)->push_back(20);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> *tmpIntVector;
    AllocateVector(&tmpIntVector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     vector<string> ivec;
```

as the starting point and modify the code to reflect that change.

You are not allocating a `vector` object. `ivec` in your code is a pointer to no where.